# Django-channels Error during WebSocket handshake: Unexpected response code: 404

Tags: django, nginx, websocket, docker-compose, django-channels

I was able to use `django-channels` but when I wanted to move with `Nginx`, `django-channels` stopped working.

I am getting this error:

```
WebSocket connection to 'ws://localhost/ws/chat/room_name/' failed: Error during WebSocket handshake: Unexpected response code: 404
```

What I tried:

1. I updated Nginx config for `location /`

Here is my `Nginx.conf`

```
upstream app {
    ip_hash;
    server app:8000;
}
server {
    client_max_body_size 100M;
    listen 80;
    server_name localhost;

location / {
    proxy_pass http://app;
    proxy_http_version 1.1;
    proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
    proxy_set_header Connection "upgrade";
    proxy_set_header Host $host;
}

location /static/admin {
    alias /app/static/admin/;
}
location /static/ {
    alias  /app/static/;
}
```

}

and here is my `nginx` in `docker-compose.yml`:

```
nginx:
  container_name: "ngnix_master"
  image: nginx:latest
  ports:
    - 80:80
  volumes:
    - ./app:/app
    - ./config/ngnix:/etc/nginx/conf.d
    - ./static:/static/
  depends_on:
    - app
```

Comment: Hi Jonathan, did you solve this issue? I'm getting same error.

Comment: Yeah I solved, with using Daphne. Try to run project with Daphne(or just asgi server).

Comment: Thanks, yesterday I fixed it as well using asgi with gunicorn.